# Stripe GraphCms typescript Insert Order Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'string'

Tags: typescript, next.js, stripe-payments, graphcms

I'm working on a 'clone' of ecommerce example
from Graphcms using typescript  so in the web hook I want to insert an order like

```
const order = {
        email: session.customer_email,
        total: session.amount_total,
        stripeCheckoutId: session.id,
        orderItems: {
            create: line_items!.data.map((item) => ({
                quantity: item.quantity,
                total: item.amount_total,
                product: {
                    connect: {
                        id: item.price?.product.metadata.productId
                    }
                }
            }))
        }
    };
```

but in this line,

```
id: item.price?.product.metadata.productId
```

I've got this error

> Property 'metadata' does not exist on type 'string | Product |
> DeletedProduct'.   Property 'metadata' does not exist on type
> 'string'.

If I print the line I can see the prop metadata
how can I fix it?

### WORKED IT OUT WITH

```
id: (item.price?.product as Stripe.Product).metadata.productId
```

Answer (score 1):

Metadata seems to be a dynamic type, so you need to add type safety to allow TypeScript to statically analyse the logic paths:

```
const product = item.price?.product;
let connectId = product;
// Note: I've not handled cases for Product | DeletedProduct
if (typeof product !== 'string') {
  connectId = product.metadata.productId
}

const order = {
        email: session.customer_email,
        total: session.amount_total,
        stripeCheckoutId: session.id,
        orderItems: {
            create: line_items!.data.map((item) => ({
                quantity: item.quantity,
                total: item.amount_total,
                product: {
                    connect: {
                        id: connectId
                    }
                }
            }))
        }
    };
```

Comment: I've got the same error :(

Comment: if you write the code on typescript playground and share a link, I can help more

Comment: Very kind thanks but it seems I've worked it out with id: (item.price?.product as Stripe.Product).metadata.productId

Comment: using the cast (`as Stripe.Product`) that will mean you could have `undefined` connectId, is it ok?

Comment: No, it's not ok but step by step :)